# Treat character as column name

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to treat a character string as a column name in case_when:

Data:

```
> df <- data.frame(col1 = c(NA, 1, 1, 0, 0),
                   col2 = c(NA, 1, 1, 0, 0),
                   col1_add=1:5, 
                   col2_add=c(6:9,NA))
> df
  col1 col2 col1_add col2_add
1   NA   NA        1        6
2    1    1        2        7
3    1    1        3        8
4    0    0        4        9
5    0    0        5       NA
```

Attempt:

```
df %>% mutate_at(c("col1_add", "col2_add"), ~case_when(as.name(str_remove(., "_add"))==1 & .>3 ~ 0, TRUE ~ .))
```

How can `str_remove(., "_add")` be treated as a column name (`col1, col2`)?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish. What is the desired result here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `across` with `cur_column()` (`cur_column()` - returns the column name, where the `str_remove` is used to remove the substring "_add", use `get` to get the value of the corresponding column, apply the logic in `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(ends_with("_add"), 
   ~ case_when(get(str_remove(cur_column(), "_add")) == 1 & 
        .x >3 ~ 0L, TRUE ~ .x)))
```

-output

```
  col1 col2 col1_add col2_add
1   NA   NA        1        6
2    1    1        2        0
3    1    1        3        0
4    0    0        4        9
5    0    0        5       NA
```

NOTE: It was previously possible to get the column name with `deparse/substitute` from `mutate_at`, but now it is not possible in the newer `dplyr` versions.  In addition, the `_at/_all` are deprecated in favor of `across`